# Select *Input History* buffer

Tags: buffers, shell

The Emacs `*shell*` has a nice command history accessible via `C-c C-l` (`comint-dynamic-list-input-ring`).  However, in classic Emacs fashion, the `*Input History*` buffer which displays the history is not selected automatically.  I want to change this.

Trouble is, I can't get a reference for the `*Input History*` buffer.

My thought is to write a wrapper around the `comint-dynamic-list-input-ring` function which calls the command and then switches to the `*Input History*` buffer.

```lisp
(defun my-see-shell-history ()
  "Open comint command history and switch to *Input History* buffer.

A wrapper around COMINT-DYNAMIC-LIST-INPUT-RING."
     (interactive)
     (comint-dynamic-list-input-ring)
     (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Input History*"))
```

This doesn't work.  Nothing happens; no error, no change in buffer focus.  Nada.

If I try the following, a new buffer called `*Input History*` is created:

1. `M-: (comint-dynamic-list-input-ring)`
2. `M-: (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Input History*")`

What's confusing is that the `*Input History*` created by `comint-dynamic-list-input-ring` seems to be a buffer that doesn't exist.  I can have the `*Input History*` buffer open on my screen (after calling `C-c C-l`) yet it doesn't show up in `M-x list-buffers`.  However, I can manually select the buffer and run `M-: (current-buffer)` and see that it is `#<buffer  *Input History*>`.

What's going on here?  How can I reference the `*Input History*` buffer?

Comment: You can't access the input history buffer as it's an ephemeral buffer (as its name begins with space) and so the `list-buffers` and `buffer-menu` commands don’t mention it.  I tried using `temp-buffer-show-hook` to spot this buffer and select its window but for some reason it was never selected - perhaps that's also because it's an ephemeral buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, we can do this just by advising the `comint-dynamic-list-input-ring` function:

```
(defadvice comint-dynamic-list-input-ring (before advice activate)
  (push ?\a unread-command-events))

(defadvice comint-dynamic-list-input-ring (after advice activate)
  (other-window 1))
```

The "after" advice does the actual work of switching to the other window - you might also want to move point to somewhere more useful of course.  The "before" advice is required as the `comint-dynamic-list-input-ring` function waits for the space key to be pressed to dismiss the input history buffer.  Here we just fake a different key which gets ignored and leaves the input history buffer up.